# Dell XPS 13 (9305) BIOS not starting

Tags: bios, reboot, dell-xps

I got a new Dell XPS 13 today but unable to go into BIOS.

I tried F2 after restart
I tried via system menu
Nothing worked the screen stays black but the machine is running.
Shortcut to restart graphic connection (ctrl shift windows B vs BSOD) brings no changes.

I noticed that I cannot boot in safe mode also.

I have no clue what could be the reason.

Comment: For accessing the firmware make sure you're using the key or key combo mentioned in the manual. You may try FN+F2 or others.

Comment: Also, from a running system, do a Restart. See if (a) there is a message on screen to enter setup and / or (b) the correct function key starts BIOS. Restart slows down to allow entering BIOS.

Comment: I used FN+F12. No auccess

Comment: From windows hold the shift key down when you click Restart, see if you can F2 into the bios at the Dell logo screen.

Comment: As for SAFE mode, interrupting boot *multiple* times by holding down the power key is a means to enter boot selection menu -- but only in emergencies, since there's a chance it might cause disk corruption.

Comment: I tried also resetting the CMOS by de-connecting accu and battery.

I do not reach UEFI and will put this "thing" back in the box to return.

First (and last) try with Dell.....

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 when Dell logo appears